# Meaning of "The personification, of the natural is exactly the tendency I wish to suppress in myself, to eliminate for good."

Tags: meaning, sentence

I'm reading *Desert Solitaire* by Edward Abbey and there is this sentence in there that confuses me:

> The personification, of the natural is exactly the tendency I wish to suppress in myself, to eliminate for good.

Can you explain what it means?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Personifications

Comment: There shouldn't be a comma after _personification_, if that's what's confusing you.

Comment: Or for a more pompous sound when spoken, you could leave the first comma, and add a second after 'natural'.

Comment: The comma is not in the original.

Answer (score 1):

A fuller context ay be gathered from [expanding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desert_Solitaire) the quote a bit.

> The personification of the natural is exactly the tendency I wish to suppress in myself, to eliminate for good. I am here not only to escape for a while the clamor and filth and confusion of the cultural apparatus but also to confront, immediately and directly if it's possible, the bare bones of existence, elemental and fundamental, the bedrock which sustains us.

He is living in the beautiful, bare-bones environment of the windblown desert wilderness of Arches National Park. It is Nature in its reality for him, not some abstract *"beautiful"* or *"benevolent"* "Nature" which "loves" us (a personification), but a real force to be dealt with respectfully (in that if we don't respect it, we will - in that environment - die).

Only in doing so (confronting and living with *real* nature) will we regain our sense of belonging in the world, for our *real place* is not the culture, material comforts, technology (name your demon here), etc. which denies nature's reality. It is in confronting and living with what nature truly is that we will find our place in the world.